# How do you write ghost notes in stop time?

Tags: notation, drums

[image][image]

From my example I have a rhythmic slashes notation (stop time), how do I change some of them to a ghost notation?
I know in regular notation you do an X, I think in slashes you do brackets, is that a correct way to do?

Comment: 'Stop time' is a new one to me! Do you consider it the same as 'syncopation'?

Comment: Well Tim, syncopation is when the melody rhythm is off beat (weak beat), stop time is telling the player to do what he want but in the rhythm I wrote for him as slashes

Comment: How can he do what he wants, when it's written exactly as it needs to be played? Do you mean on different drums?

Comment: Well those are slashes and not notes, it doesn’t mean it’s a snare notes. The slashes can be either kick, snare HH toms or whatever the drummer thinks and want to do with that information.

Comment: Also, if you put that for bass, you put a chord symbol at top so that the player knows what to play on that chord scale, the same for piano or guitar, they have that rhythmic notation, but it’s not for specific notes or the way they suppose to play a chord

Comment: It's just that heads on the middle line usually mean that's for snare. Each drum /hi-hat/cymbal has its own place on a stave. That's how a reading drummer knows which ones to hit. And you have written out a specific rhythm for someone to play - then said 'please yourself'. That, I don't understand.

Comment: Yes I know that each drum/cymbals has its own note on a stave, if it was regular notes and not slashes, it means snare notes, but in this case it can be everything. Sometimes you need to trust a player to let him do what he thinks it’s the best, if you don’t, write him simple notes.

Comment: And syncopation can be *anything* that moves off beat - melody, rhythm, chords, accompaniment - anything. 'Rhythmic contradiction'. Seems like it's analogous to 'stop time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either/or! They can be written as 'x' *or* as real notes bracketed. It's less messy (and easier) to use 'x'. As long as the head is in the appropriate place - as your example for snare - then players will understand.